# Beanstalk UI env trying to access Beanstalk API env connected to RDS in same VPC - results in Connect Timedout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

Beanstalk A - Hosts the UI
Beanstalk B - Hosts the API
RDS - Hosts the SQL DB and is not public

1) I didn't attach B to RDS in configuration, but I am accessing RDS through B by setting up env variables and setting the security group of RDS to allow inbound MYSQL from B
2) I can ssh into B and access RDS through B
3) I have both A and B behind load balancer and behind https
4) Both A and B running on javascript/node js
5) B has inbound rule to allow All TCP from A

PROBLEM:

When I go to A's url and do a search which eventually hits B, I get a 'Connect ETIMEDOUT' ERROR.

I realize this has something to do with allowing access, but I have security group of RDS allowing B and security group of B allowing A. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are the API calls happening? Is A making API calls to B from the server-side code, or in Front-end JavaScript code?

---

**If A is making API calls to B from server-side code:**

First make sure that the following is true:
Load Balancer B accepts traffic from the security group assigned to EC2 server A. EC2 server B accepts traffic from the security group assigned to Load Balancer B.

You may need to make the load balancer for B private, so that the traffic between A and B will stay within the VPC. If the traffic is going from service A out of the VPC and back in to the VPC to hit service B then the association to the security groups is lost, and so the security group rule for load balancer B will not work.

---

**If A is making API calls from the front-end JavaScript code:**

The security group assigned to load balancer B will need to have the same rules as load balancer A, which I assume allow all HTTP/HTTPS traffic from any source. This is because the API calls are actually happening over the Internet, originating from a user's web browser on their local computer, not from server A.

Comment: A is making API calls to B through jquery (front end code). Then B will actually connect to the private DB when the request comes in. At least this is how it should work.  Edit: Yes Both ELB have http/https traffic from any source enabled.

Comment: So Beanstalk A is irrelevant to this problem them. You should be able to test hitting Beanstalk B directly using a tool like Postman. What are the security group rules of the EC2 instances in Beanstalk B?

Comment: got it working! it was a stupid typo, where I was using the wrong port. Otherwise your answer was in line with what I had, security groups need to be in the inbound rule